# Design my Entity so that I can use an Entity Field for a specific use case

Tags: forms, symfony, model

I've a `Candidate` entity which have an `$xmlContent` attribute, This attribute is used to get some references to other Entities (Country, Citizenship, ...), the $xmlContent value contain the Ids of these entities as follow,

```
<data>
  <countryId>2</countryId>
  <citizenship>4</citizenship>
  <!-- ... -->
</data>
```

**Note:** I know, The model was badly designed! I can't modify it, This was one of the project **weird** constraints when I started working on it.

So, I created getters and setters for each `Id` of the $xmlContent value.

**The problem,**

I created a Form to edit a Candidate object (including the $xmlContent Ids), I then Added getters and setters to get these values (getCountry(), getCitizenship(), ...)

The problem is that I want to let the user choose the value of `Country` (for example) from a list of all available countries, I also have to put the right country as a default one.

I then decided to use an Entity Field,

```
    ->add('country', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'MyBundle:Country',
        'query_builder' => function(CountryRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->orderBy('c.rank', 'ASC');
        },
        'property' => 'Name'
    ))
```

But, here I had another problem, the getter I'm using to get a candidate Country returns an "Id" but the Entity Field expect an Object.

**My Question,**

What is the best way to handle this?

**My Constraint,**

I want to keep my code as clean as possible :)

Comment: You will want to create a FormType which handles country and citisenship and anything else in xmlContent.  Then use a data transformer to transform xmlContent to and from individual fields i.e. have the data transformer return an array.  Couple of threads on this and there is a cookbook example on dealing with the entity issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should look into [DataTransformers](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) and [EventSubscribers](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html).

You could use a DataTransformer to parse you `xmlContent` into discrete properties and populate their fields, e.g. `country` and `citizenship`.

Using an EventSubscriber you can a) on `PRE_BIND` reverseTransform the form data into `xmlContent`* and b) transform your form elements, e.g. fetch countries and create/alter a choice-element `country` from the data.

* DataTransformers won't work here, as you do not just want to reverseTransform, i.e. string into entity, but rather want to merge and transform data from multiple fields (country, citizenship, etc.) into a single field (xmlContent).

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you added getters and setters, I guess you're allowed to modify the model, but not its representation in the database or the mapping, am I right?

I think your getters / setters should not return ids / change xmlContent. Instead, the getters should read the ids and build the correponding entites if they were not built previously. The setters should just modify the former objects, and you should implement lifecycle callbacks so that xmlContent is up to date before it is persisted.

That way, the form would easily be bound to your data.